# Yii2: How to add separate api module in root directory?

Tags: rest, api, yii2

I have yii2 basic project with working web application functionality and now i want to add api functionality for this application.Currently i have directory stucture as

```
root
+ api
 + config
 + modules
 + v1
   + controllers
+.htaccess
+index.php
+index.php
+.htaccess
+ web
+ config
+ controllers
...
```

Now i am requesting `/api/v1/controller/action` but is getting 404 not found as response. Anything i have to configure?

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up everything correctly and added the new `api` alias in the `common/bootstrap.php` file like `Yii::setAlias('api', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/api');`, you need to define the rules under `urlManager` in order to access the specific controller action inside your `api/config/main.php`.

For example I have a controller inside the `api/modules/v1/controller/` with the name `Lead` and have two actions with the name `actionTest()` and `actionLists()` and i want to be able to send `POST` request to the `actionLists()` and `GET` request to the `actionTest()` then i will define them in the `UrlManager` like below

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'pluralize' => false,
                'controller' => 'v1/lead',
                'tokens' => [
                    '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
                ],
                'extraPatterns' => [
                    'POST create' => 'create',
                    'GET test' => 'test'
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
```

Now I can send `POST` request to `http://example.com/api/v1/lead/list` and `GET` request to `http://example.com/api/v1/lead/test?id=1234`

Note: Notice the `'pluralize'=>false` for the rule if no set you will notice the controller ID `lead` appears in plural form as `leads` in the endpoint URLs. This is because [`yii\rest\UrlRule`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule) automatically pluralizes controller IDs when creating child URL rules. You may disable this behavior by setting [`yii\rest\UrlRule::$pluralize`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$pluralize-detail) to be false.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad i am using basic template and it seems as for advanced package.